# Run my SparkJob on apache job-server

Tags: cassandra, sbt, apache-spark, datastax, spark-jobserver

I have a problem with Apache job-server and my .jar with SparkJob. 
I have VirtualBox with DataStax. There are Cassandra and Spark. I install Apache job-server from [git job-server](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver). I want run examples so I write `sbt job-server-tests/package` and next run job-server from terminal `sbt re-start`

Examples from job-server work

1. `curl --data-binary @/home/job-server/job-server-tests/target/job.jar localhost:8090/jars/test`
2. `curl -d "" 'localhost:8090/jobs?appName=test&classPath=spark.jobserver.LongPiJob'`

Problem is when I make my .jar
I use eclipse on Windows with Scala IDE. I installed sbteclipse plugin and I made folder `C:\Users\user\scalaWorkspace\LongPiJob` with scala project. I run cmd, go to this folder and run `sbt eclipse` `sbt compile` and `sbt package`. Then I copy .jar to VirtualBox. Next I use **1**. curl command. When I use **2**. curl command I get a error

> job-server[ERROR] Exception in thread "pool-25-thread-1" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.forszpaniak.LongPiJob$.validate(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;)Lspark/jobserver/SparkJobValidation;
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor$$anonfun$spark$jobserver$JobManagerActor$$getJobFuture$4.apply(JobManagerActor.scala:225)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

in terminal where I started server. In curl terminal I get

> [root@localhost spark-jobserver]# curl -d "stress.test.longpijob.duration=15" 'localhost:8090/jobs?appNametestJob1.5&classPath=com.forszpaniak.LongPiJob'
>   {
>     "status": "ERROR",
>     "result": {
>       "message": "Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/4538158c-com.forszpaniak.LongPiJob#-713999361]] after [10000 ms]",
>       "errorClass": "akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException",
>       "stack": ["akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:333)", "akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$7.run(Scheduler.scala:117)", "scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.scala$concurrent$Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$$unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:694)", "scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:691)", "akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(Scheduler.scala:467)", "akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.executeBucket$1(Scheduler.scala:419)", "akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.nextTick(Scheduler.scala:423)", "akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.run(Scheduler.scala:375)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)"]
>     }

I my .jar I use code from example LongPiJob.scala. I have searched some information about this server error and I think, it can be version problem?

**java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.forszpaniak.LongPiJob$.validate(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;)Lspark/jobserver/SparkJobValidation;**

I think instead Object should be SparkContext...

> I use
>   DataStax: 4.6
>   job-server: 0.5.1
>   scala: 2.10.4
>   sbt: 0.13
>   spark: 1.1.0

**[My test code](https://github.com/forszpanen/cassandra-spark-jobserver-tests)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Spark JobServer 0.5.1 is compatible with spark 1.3.0, you are using 1.1.0. I would try changing that to 0.4.1 first.

```
  Version   Spark Version
   0.3.1    0.9.1
   0.4.0    1.0.2
   0.4.1    1.1.0
   0.5.0    1.2.0
   0.5.1    1.3.0
```

Then you may want to modify the startup_server.sh script such that it uses the DSE classpath. This should help you avoid other errors in the future.

Something like

```
dse spark-submit --class $MAIN $appdir/spark-job-server.jar --driver-java-options "$GC_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS $LOGGING_OPTS" $conffile 2>&1 &
```

Here is a repo where I modified the server startup script to work with DSE (4.7 but it should be similar for 4.6)

https://github.com/RussellSpitzer/spark-jobserver/blob/DSP-47-EAP3/bin/server_start.sh

Comment: Thx, your response helps me ;) I have had wrong version job-server. I have another question but I'll make new topic on SO.

Comment: I use your server_start.sh script but I have two issues. How can I stop job server because server_stop.sh doesn't stop this and I don't see any job in SparkUI even spark-sumbit --class spark.jobserver.JobServer etc.? I can see my jobs only in JobserverUI